# Combining CSS Scale Transform with Background Position Produces Gap in FF & Safari

Tags: css, background, css-transitions, scale

When you combine CSS3 a `scale()` transform on a div with adjacent `inline-block` children (no text elements between them) like below, you expect the entire parent div to be scaled as if the two elements were one.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="img-1"></div>
    <div class="img-2"></div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.container {
      transform: scale(1.5);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
      line-height: 0;
      font-size: 0;
}

.img-1, .img-2 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* This is contrived. The children don't need the same bg */
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/g/250/250');
}
```

This happens correctly in all recent browsers with CSS3 transform support.

However, adding and adjusting the `background-position` of `.img-1` or `.img-2` produces an inconsistent and occasionally unreproducible visual glitch in Firefox and Safari (see below) but renders correctly in Chrome and Internet Explorer 10 & 11 (*gasp*).

```
.img-1, img-2 {
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/g/250/250') -1px -1px;
}
```

The best way I can describe the glitch is that between the images an opaque (or sometimes semi-opaque) gap appears. Interestingly enough, the glitch only occurs on OSX 10.10.3 (possibly earlier) but not on Windows 7.

The screenshots below are OSX 10.10.3 and Windows 7. I've added a red background so the gap is more visible. To try it for yourself: http://jsbin.com/dumekayiha/1/edit.

#### Chrome 45.0.2421.0 OSX

*Correct Behavior*

[image: Chrome 45.0.2421.0 OSX]

#### Chrome 43.0.2357.81 Windows

*Correct Behavior*

[image: Chrome 43.0.2357.81 Windows]

---

#### Firefox 38.0.5 OSX

**Incorrect Behavior**

[image: Firefox 38.0.5 OSX]

#### Firefox 38.0.5 Windows

*Correct Behavior*

[image: Firefox 38.0.5 Windows]

---

#### Firefox Developer Edition 40.0a2 (2015-06-02) OSX

**Incorrect Behavior**

[image: Firefox Developer Edition 40.0a2 OSX]

#### Firefox Developer Edition 40.0a2 (2015-06-02) Windows

*Correct Behavior*

[image: Firefox Developer Edition 40.0a2 Windows]

---

#### IE 10 Windows

*Correct Behavior*

[image: IE 10 Windows]

---

#### IE 11 Windows

*Correct Behavior*

[image: IE 11 Windows]

---

#### Safari 8.0.6 (10600.6.3) OSX

**Incorrect Behavior**

[image: Safari 8.0.6 OSX]

---

In FF and FF Dev edition on OSX 10.10.3, I can sometimes get the effect to disappear by resizing the browser window. At certain (seemingly random) dimensions, the gap disappears. Additionally in FF on OSX (not Dev edition), if I add `transform-style: preserve-3d;` in the inspector and then spam click the enable/disable property checkbox, I can get the gap to disappear. Additionally, sometimes using strange combinations of `background`, `background-image`, `background-repeat`, and `background-position` can get the gap to disappear in FF and FF Developer Edition, however I found it to unreliable, inconsistent, and unreproducible (perhaps modifying the styles triggered the same repaint that spamming `transform-style` did?).

If it is at all relevant, the Windows screenshots are from Windows 7 running on Virutalbox. However, I had a friend with Windows pull up the jsbin and he confirmed that my windows screenshots mirrored what he saw. Additionally, (and not that it is at all relevant due to low market share) Safari 5 on windows suffers the same issue as Safari on OSX.

When I get the gap to disappear, neither image jumps to the left or right. Instead, the 1px line that was transparent becomes the proper 1px leftmost line of the right image. This behavior and the differences between browsers and OS's makes me believe this is just a Firefox and Safari Bug.

Am I correct that this is a bug? (I've prepared a bug report to submit in this case). And if so, is there a CSS hack I can use to reliably prevent this glitch?

---

**EDIT:** Further investigation has revealed that the gap only occurs when both of the offset values are odd numbers (note that I am resizing the divs so that the `background image dimensions + 2*offset = div width`).

Comment: Why the `-1px -1px`? If I remove that the images align.

Comment: @frontend_dev Right. But, consider the scenario where the image is a spritemap and you need to access a specific rectangle within the rectangle. Regardless, changing `background-position` shouldn't produce this unexpected behavior.

Comment: Yeah thats a point. I looked at this again and I can imagine that this actually some kind of rendering bug. Reminds me of these rounding errors when using percentage based layouts. Not sure if you can do anything about that ... What you could do is only to use even pixel sizes, like -2, -4 and so on. It seems to only happen with odd sizes, so in combination with your 1.5 scaling this looks like a kind of rounding error, too. Of course you have to carefully plan what you want to do and when doing actual animations it can happen you see these lines while scaling up.

Comment: @frontend_dev That's funny that you just discovered that! I was just playing with that myself. Unfortunately, although I wish it was, using even offsets isn't really an option (I don't control the spritemap and it's very dense so off by 1 pixel contains part of another image). I agree with your assessment of this being a rounding error. Would be interesting to know how everyone else handles it since it seems that only Firefox really got it really wrong (the safari gap is semi-transparent).

Comment: Thats the reason I leave some gaps when I use spritemaps. (Actually I mostly use inline data-uris now, they do not have these problems). Unfortunately there might be no solution for you, as you cannot change the FF engine. As a side note it is interesting that FF fails here, there are many cases where it's just the opposite situation, i.e. FF handling percentage rounding better than the rest.

Comment: @frontend_dev I agree my specific scenario isn't optimal. I'll try percentage positioning. Unfortunately, this isn't very mainable, because representing 1px in percentages can't be done for every width/height.

Comment: Well with percentages you might run into problems as well, maybe this time in other browsers ;) Also keep in mind what happens when a user zooms the page to 150%. This was an issue I also had with spritemaps then leaking some pixels from neighboring sprites, so I added some gaps to be safe from this stuff.

Comment: @frontend_dev I would've just used a css hack to target FF. Unfortunately, `1px/250px = 0.4%`, however using `background-position: -0.4% -0.4%;` looks the same. You have a decent point with 150% zoom. My specific use case is Google Docs like (which breaks when you zoom the page), so I'm not very concerned about that here, but in general you're right that that's a legitimate concern.

Comment: You cannot prevent the user from zooming a page. So if your layout breaks, then it would be a deal breaker for me. Same goes for the case when a user decides to zoom the font-size. Imho you should let them do that. Of course you cannot guarantee the layout is still intact when zooming a LOT, but at least a certain amount should be possible. Also keep in mind that you can combat layout issues when zooming by using media queries.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder just out of curiosity have you tried removing the HTML spaces in the code ( I know you are using `font-size:0` for fixing `inline-block` gap), other thing you could try is this: `-moz-transform-origin: 0 0`  in your `.container ` (using the values that might fit better). see more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin). Since your issue occurs in OSX I can't debug it, sorry.

Comment: @frontend_dev Of course. It's not really the layout that breaks by the core component (its more of a web app). It has its own settings page for things like font size to account for the fact that zooming breaks it. So I'd agree with you for general purpose sites, but given that my case is specific, it's the only way to go. I wasn't aware you could target zoom levels with media queries. That's a good tip. Thanks!

Comment: @dippas Good thought. My example is really contrived (I'm actually building the elements so there is no text in between). I tried your hunch and removed all spaces, but unfortunately the bug persisted. Setting `transform-origin` is a great idea. I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: @dippas Unfortunately, Firefox still has a gap even with `transform-origin`. Thanks for the suggestion, though! Any other hacks I can look into?